# SwiftUI: How to align icon to left side of centered text field?

Tags: swiftui, icons, textfield

I've got a TextField in SwiftUI that is centered on the screen. I want to add a pencil icon immediately. to the left of it to indicate that it is editable - how can I do this? I've tried embedding both the TextField and Image in an HStack like this:

```
HStack {
  Spacer()
  Image(systemName: "pencil")
  TextField(...)
}
```

But that only yields something like this: [image]
where the textfield is no longer centered and the pencil is aligned to the left of the screen.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: how do you center the Textfield? (without the icon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do it:

```
        TextField("", text: $input)
            .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                    .offset(x: -24, y: 0)
            }
```

Comment: this kind of works, but if the text length gets long enough, it covers the pencil icon. any way around that?

Comment: Can you share your full code with the TextField. Its unclear to me how you center it.

Comment: its in a vstack, which has alignment: .center

Comment: ? that wouldn't center it as the TextField always takes all available space in width. Do you apply a frame?

Comment: ah I should've specified, the the textfield takes the entire width and i use multilineTextAlignment(.center) to get the text in the middle. I came up with a slightly weird solution that changes the width of the textfield based on the length of the entered text, which works for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct CustomTextFieldView: View {
     @State private var text: String = ""
    
     var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            textfeild
                .padding()
        }
    }
    var textfeild: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "pencil")
            TextField("Edit me!", text: $text)
        }
        .textFieldStyle(DefaultTextFieldStyle())
    }
}

struct CustomTextFieldView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomTextFieldView()
    }
}
```